# sympyの1変数不等式「Inequality Solvers」について教えて下さい。

Tags: python, sympy

式      :k**2-40>0
条件    :kは整数,k>0
ほしい解:k>=7

プログラム①:symbol定義は、だめでした。
プログラム②:Unionの要素の取り出し方を教えて下さい。
プログラム③:solveの結果の要素の取り出し方を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします

プログラム①

```
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k',integer=True,positive=True)
ineq = 'k**2-40>0'
ans1=solve_univariate_inequality(sympify(ineq), k, relational=False)
print('#',ineq,':',ans1)
#
# (以下エラー)抜粋
# line 633, in solve_univariate_inequality
#     raise ValueError(filldedent('''
# ValueError:
# k**2 - 40 > 0 contains imaginary parts which cannot be made 0 for any
# value of k satisfying the inequality, leading to relations like I < 0.
```

プログラム②

```
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k')
ineq = 'k**2-40>0'
ans1=solve_univariate_inequality(sympify(ineq), k, relational=False)
print('#',ineq,':',ans1)
# k**2-40>0 : Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10)), Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo))
```

プログラム③

```
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k')
ineq = 'k**2-40>0'
print('#',ineq,':',solve(ineq))
# k**2-40>0 : ((-oo < k) & (k < -2*sqrt(10))) | ((k < oo) & (2*sqrt(10) < k))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> プログラム③:solveの結果の要素の取り出し方を教えて下さい。

```py
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k', integer=True, positive=True)
ineq = k**2 - 40 > 0
solution = solve(ineq).evalf()
for i in preorder_traversal(solution):
  if isinstance(i, Float):
    solution = solution.subs(i, ceiling(i)) 

solution = solution.replace(StrictLessThan, LessThan)
print(solution)
=>
7 <= k
```

Answer (score 0):

wolframalphaで
k**2-40>0 , k>0 整数
https://ja.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k**2-40%3E0+%2C+k%3E0+%E6%95%B4%E6%95%B0

結果:
k>=7

Answer (score -2):

プログラム④

```
from sympy import *
import math
print('k>=',math.ceil(float(sqrt(40))))
# k>= 7
```